# Slerp Camera in Coroutine

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine

My camera is not a child of target gameObject. I have to Slerp Camera to my moveable gameObject. I used Coroutine for that which works in FixedUpdate(). I tried to write it in Update(), but anyway it doesn't work well (I guess problem with frames compatibility). Help me to improve the code. Thanks in advance.

```
// Public parameters
public GameObject player;
public float maxDistance = 3f;

// Positions for Slerp
private Vector3 startPosition;
private Vector3 endPosition;

// Components
private Transform playerTransform;
private Transform thisTransform;
private float timeSinceStarted;

void Awake () {
    playerTransform = this.player.transform;
    thisTransform = this.transform;
}

void Update ()
{
    this.transform.LookAt (player.transform);
    startPosition = thisTransform.position;

    endPosition = new Vector3 (playerTransform.position.x, playerTransform.position.y + 3.5f, playerTransform.position.z);

    if (MoveStates.Instance.mustWalkBackward ()) {
        endPosition = new Vector3 (playerTransform.position.x, playerTransform.position.y, playerTransform.position.z);
    }

    if (MoveStates.Instance.mustWalkForward ()) {
        endPosition = new Vector3 (playerTransform.position.x, playerTransform.position.y + 2f, playerTransform.position.z);
    }
    timeSinceStarted = 0f;
    StartCoroutine (MoveFunction ());
}

IEnumerator MoveFunction()
{   yield return new WaitForSeconds (Mathf.Epsilon);
    timeSinceStarted += Time.deltaTime;
    if (Vector3.Distance (startPosition, endPosition) > maxDistance) {
        this.thisTransform.position = Vector3.Slerp (this.startPosition, this.endPosition, timeSinceStarted);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're using the *Coroutine* the wrong way. I'd recommend to do it like this :

```
IEnumerator MoveFunction()
{   
    while (Vector3.Distance (startPosition, endPosition) > maxDistance)
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.Slerp (startPosition, endPosition, Time.deltaTime);
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    }
}
```

But this is the usage if you only want to move your **Camera** punctually. In your situation, I wouldn't use a *Coroutine* and I guess you want it to "follow" your player continuously : you should use the *Slerp* in the *Update/FixedUpdate/LateUpdate* methods (I have a preference for *LateUpdate* when it comes to **Camera** position adjustments. Something like this should be enough I guess :

```
void LateUpdate()
{
    if (Vector3.Distance (startPosition, endPosition) > maxDistance)
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.Slerp (startPosition, endPosition, Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

By the way : you can call simply `tranform` instead of `this.transform` and `startPosition` instead of `this.startPosition`.